# What is most useful from C# to code for Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine

Does knowing of async and await is useful in Unity?

or knowing asynchronic programming is useful in Unity, or Unity do everything for us?

Comment: Hi welcome to Stackoverflow! Your question is not very clear. Please elaborate more on what you are asking in a simpler way.

Answer (score 1):

async and await are useful when doing certain i/o operations, for example when accessing the serial port (which is blocking in Mono otherwise), but this is a realatively narrow area.

Otherwise, normal daily tasks are typically performed on the main thread, as Unity absolutely hates when stuff is called out of order, pretty much crashes immediately.

As for doing multiple things in the background, Unity provides a very conveinient mechanism called Coroutines. Its not actually multithreading but has almost none of the issues real multithreading has.

Comment: so it seems i dont need learn multithreading for unity at all, as Tasks and others?

Comment: no, unity provides a very convinient way of doing multiple things 'at the same time' called Coroutines. its not actually multithreading but has almost none of the issues real multithreading has

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronus programming for Unity is probably something you really don't need to learn. I mean, if you want go for it. Always nice to know more about coding.

Unity has certain execution order for all its methods. Just check out the documentation:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ExecutionOrder.html

As the other answered already states, certain I/O operations, but if you are relatively new to Unity, don't bother about it right now.
Use StartCoroutine(Function()) from the usual functions like Update, Start, Awake or whatever.

Usually you would start IEnumerators in coroutines. Check out Unity docs on that one too:
https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html

Cheers.